# JavaFX TextArea style with css

Tags: java, css, javafx, textarea

I want to know how to change the inside border color that appears in the text area. I want to delete de blue transparent border inside the red border of the text area. I have checked the modena.css file but I can not find the solution.

[image: textArea]

What I have in my css file:

```
.text-area:focused {
 -fx-background-color:  white;
 -fx-border-color: rgba(229,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextArea has an additional border/background on its content. To change/get rid of it, you need an additonal style in your css.

Something like

```
.text-area:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color:  white;
}
```

not sure if that's safe enough: it is [not documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) (or at least I could not find any doc for it), only available as implementation, f.i. in the extracted [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to get rid of the auto-generated focus effects of a textarea:

```
* {
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-border-style: none;
}
```

or

```
.textarea {
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-border-style: none;
-fx-background-radius: 0.0px;
-fx-border-radius: 0.0px;
}
```

To get rid of all the default styling, which includes a rounded border...